# How can I mine PeerCoin?

Tags: miner-configuration, peercoin

I was wondering how I could mine peercoin - I already have experience mining Bitcoins and Litecoins, yet I can't seem to find any software where I can mine them - I would like to be able to mine them on my mac with a GPU, so any applications, or terminal commands would be a great help... I already have my Peercoin wallet and everything set up. I have tried CGMiner except in the recent update they completely dumped support for GPU mining.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [simple guide](https://talk.peercoin.net/t/guide-for-cpu-and-gpu-peercoin-mining-on-mac-os-x-tested/1067) from peercointalk to help you mine on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Here you're.Peercoin Starter from A -Z. Best guide you can find in the World
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLb4XAiA2P4&list=PLBt4zAxcWonnA8-InWGUEw-UZofHdUIeT

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CGMiner dropped GPU mining support from version 3.8 upwards - you need to get 3.7.0 which still has it and still works like a charm (at least on Windows and Linux). Be careful to check at a profitability calculator if it's worth it - given too many people with ASICs have diverted them for other SHA256-powered coins, you might not cover your costs.

Or you could simply buy some Peercoins in an exchange and leave your client on and connected all the time: [the way PPC works](http://www.peercoin.net/minting.php), you'll get a small interest on your coins over time (circa 1% annually). Or you can simply buy them, and after 90+ days (or even 1 year) start up your client and leave it connected for some hours - you'd still earn some riskless interest, but less than if you'd left the client on the whole time, as discussed in-depth  in the answers to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9540/are-all-strategies-to-mine-ppcoin-proof-of-stake-blocks-equivalent).